# Name Progression

Tags: pattern, knowledge

You know those puzzles where you have to get from one word to another through a series of steps by only changing a letter between each step?

Well we're going to something similar with names.

Start with one name and progress to the last, only changing one of the names at each step.

Here's an example (with made up names)

John Smith
Jim Smith
Jim Jones
Sam Jones
Sam Brown
Mary Brown

Pretty simple right?

Well, I'm not going to give you the first or last name; you'll have to deduce them from my clues! These clues aren't necessarily direct references to the names, but may just describe an aspect of them or something famous about them. Here you go:

> Precedes You Bastards
>   Constant Cameo
>   Short Punch
>   Bereaved Playboy
>   Who Says?
>   Shouted Thrice

Two things:

- There is 1 step where the first/last name gets switched (i.e. it could go from Hugh Grant to Grant Hill)
- The first name of the last person sounds like the last name of the first person

I figure this'll be solved pretty quickly, but I have learned my lesson about dumping a BILLION PUZZLES into a single post, so maybe I will make others if people like this one.

The answer must include all six names and reasoning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precedes You Bastards

> Stan Marsh (South Park, "You killed Kenny, You Bastards!" Not sure if the quote is ever applied to Stan, but it fits)

Constant Cameo

> Stan Lee (Marvel Studios, makes a cameo in nearly every film)

Short Punch

> Bruce Lee (Martial Arts)

Bereaved Playboy

> Bruce Wayne (Batman, he's definitely a playboy!)

Who Says?

> Wayne Brady (Actor on Whose Line is it Anyway?)

Shouted Thrice

> Marsha Brady (Brady Bunch, "Marsha, Marsha, Marsha!")

And to the hint,

> Marsha ~ Marsh

Comment: Well done! Just as an aside, "Short Punch" is actually a reference to something specific. :)